# Summary of different types of TQFT?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, cobordism, topological-quantum-field-theory

For the purposes of this question, a TQFT comprises the following data:

1. An "upper dimenison" $n \in \mathbb N$.
2. A "lower dimension" $0 \leq l \leq n$.
3. A choice of structure group $X$, i.e. a commutative diagram of spaces

$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD} 
X_l @>>> X_{l+1} @>>> \cdots @>>> X_n \\ 
@VVV @VVV @VVV @VVV \\ 
BO(l) @>>> BO(l+1) @>>> \cdots @>>> BO(n)
\end{CD}$

(Typically these squares are taken to be homotopy pullbacks, so that the structure group is specfied by the choice of a single map $X_n \to BO(n)$. I will assume for the rest of the question that this is the case, and simply refer to "$X_n$" as "$X$".)

From this data, one constructs the $n$-dimensional, $(n-l)$-extended bordism group with structure group $X$, denoted $Bord_{(n,l)}^X$. Objects are $l$-manifolds with $X_l$-structure on the tangent bundle, 1-morphisms are bordisms with $X_{l+1}$-structure which restricts appropriately, etc, on up to dimension $n$, and then above that the morphisms are given by structure-preserving diffeomorphisms. An *$(n,l,X)$-TQFT* is then defined to be a symmetric monoidal $(\infty,(n-l))$-functor out of $Bord_{(n,l)}^X$.

What confuses me is that there are special names for $(n,l,X)$-TQFT's for various choices of $(n,l,X)$, and I can't keep them straight. So I'm asking the following

**Question:** For which values of $(n,l,X)$ do $(n,l,X)$-TQFT's have a special name?

Ideally it would be nice to see these names laid out systematically in some kind of table.

Here are some examples I'm aware of:

- Let $n=1,l=0,X = BSO(1) = EO(1)$. A $(1,0,EO(1))$-TQFT is called a *dualizable object*.
- More generally, let $n$ be arbitrary, $l=0$, and $X_n = EO(n)$. By the cobordism hypothesis, an $(n,0,EO(n))$-TQFT is called a *fully dualizable object*.
- Let $n=2,l=1, X = BSO(2)$. I *believe* that a $(2,1,BSO(2))$-TQFT is called a *commutative Frobenius algebra* -- unless it's actually a *special* commutative Frobenius algebra?

Here are a few more which I'm wondering about in particular:

- Let $n=1,l=0,X = BO(1)$. Then a $(1,0,BO(1))$-TQFT is some sort of "self-dual object". Is there a more precise name used here?
- Do commutative Frobenius algebras and special commutative Frobenius *each* have TQFT interpretations?
- What is a Calabi-Yau object exactly? Does it fit into this framework?

Comment: It seems to me you are asking about classification Theorems for particular kinds of TQFTs? Here are some: 

When $n=3$, $l=1$ and $X=BSO(3)$ you get "anomaly free modular objects". https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0945 

When $n=3$, $l=2$ and $X=BSO(3)$ you get "J-algebras" https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.0668.

There are also cases where a classification of fully dualizable objects in some specific target gives a subexample of your $l=0$, $X_n=EO(n)$ example. 

The $n=2$, $l=1$, $X=BSO(2)$ corresponds to commutative Frobenius algebras: https://mat.uab.cat/~kock/TQFT/FS.pdf

Comment: Building on what Manuel said, I disagree with your question phrasing. Some TQFTs do have names. "Dijkgraaf--Witten theory". "Reshetikhin--Turaev theory". Etc. But what you call a "name" is not a name, but rather a classification theorem. Commutative Frobenius algebras were around long before TQFTs were. Frobenius studied them, for example. The name "commutative Frobenius algebra" names some specific structure in algebra, which by *theorem* is equivalent to an oriented unextended 2D TQFT. That theorem is a nontrivial statement about the topology of 2-manifolds.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd You're [telling me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant#The_parable) that an elephant is like a snake, which is fair. But the premise of my question was that an elephant is like a fan. Anyway, it seems like these are maybe war elephants in the middle of a battle, because I'm looking around and seeing an ear here, a trunk there, sometimes just legs or tusks, and I don't even know which ears connect to which trunks. Maybe the state of the field is such that I'm better off asking about each trunk I see individually?

Comment: I agree the phrasing is slightly confusing. If you're asking for a name, I'd call those "$X$ structured $(n-l)-1$ extended $n$-dimensional TFTs". If you're asking about classification then it often also depends on the target, e.g. "commutative Frobenius algebra"  is correct only if the target is $\operatorname{Vect}$, or rather some discrete symmetric monoidal category, unless you decide to call oriented 2d TFT a Frobenius algebra, which I think you shouldn't :)

Comment: @Adrien I think I _would_ call any once-extended oriented 2d TFT a "commutative Frobenius algebra" -- or if clarity is needed, I'd call it "a commutative Frobenius monoid in C" -- what's wrong with this?

Comment: Well, my point is that this is valid only if $C$ is discrete, i.e. a symmetric monoidal 1-category. In general I'd argue the correct higher analog of a Frobenius algebra, meaning "a commutative algebra with a non-degenerate trace" is "a cyclic framed $E_2$-algebra" and it's just not the case that those are the same as oriented 2d TFT in general.

Comment: Oh -- for me "commutative" means "$E_\infty$" by default.

Comment: Well then that's even less true: the value on the circle of a 2d TFT is only $E_2$ in general.

Comment: @TimCampion Sure. I'm not disagreeing with the content, simply with the usage of "name". Definitely it could be nice to have a summary of which classes of TQFTs have reasonable classifications, or in other words a reasonable generators-and-relations presentation of the corresponding bordism category. I doubt very much that any class with $l \geq 2$ will have a known classification. Also, when $n \gg 0$, you might find yourself asking to understand a cell complex for $BO(n)$, or you might decide to demand that the target be discrete and so only need a truncation of $BO(n)$. And so on.